# How I can hide this php echo?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a php code that gets the lat and long of the users in a database, is like this:

```
$data = array();
echo " var latlong = [ " ;

for ( $x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows( $result); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result);
    echo " [ " , $data[ $x][ 'lat' ], " , " , $data[ $x][ 'lng' ], " ] " ;
    if ( $x <= ( mysql_num_rows( $result) - 2) ) {
        echo " , " ;
    }
}
    echo " ]; " ;

 json_encode($data);
```

And then in my index.php I have this to read it in javascript:

```
var latlong =  <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

The problem is that my php prints all the values in the screen, how I can hide that?

Comment: How about removing all echos from your PHP? Btw, are you json_encoding an array that you've already json_encoded?

Comment: just comment out the `echo`s with `//`? You reference `$data` in the encode anyway

Comment: If you want to get Information from a PHP page without echoing everything you should use an AJAX-Request.

Comment: You should also stop using the old, insecure and deprecated `mysql_*`-functions and use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to understand the code :

```
$data = array();
echo " var latlong = [ " ;

for ( $x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows( $result); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result);
    echo " [ " , $data[ $x][ 'lat' ], " , " , $data[ $x][ 'lng' ], " ] " ;
    if ( $x <= ( mysql_num_rows( $result) - 2) ) {
        echo " , " ;
    }
}

echo " ]; " ;

json_encode($data);
```

Since there is some "echo" in the code, for example : `echo " [ " , $data[ $x][ 'lat' ], " , " , $data[ $x][ 'lng' ], " ] " ;`, this print the json.
Just remove thoses `echo` or comment them using `//` or `/* echo part */`

Comment: I just remove all the echo and now the php doesnt save the array correctly, actually it doesnt make the array :'(

Comment: Strange, btw you just need to remove the echo from the script but keep the  `<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;`

Comment: for ( $x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows( $result); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result);
     " [ " , $data[ $x][ 'lat' ], " , " , $data[ $x][ 'lng' ], " ] " ;
    if ( $x <= ( mysql_num_rows( $result) - 2) ) {
         " , " ;
    }
}
     " ]; " ;

file_put_contents('filename.txt', print_r($data, true));
 json_encode($data);

Comment: I add that prints me the array in a file and it doesnt do it. It doesnt create the array

Comment: You need to remove all the line that start with the echo, not just the "word" echo

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap your JS Code in `script` tags (and you also output `var latlong` twice).

```
<script>
  <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```